# C# Facebook SDK - 'Facebook.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'id'

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

With the C# Facebook SDK, I am unable to run my application when it's on my staging domain (mathias.testing.fablelane.com), but I can run it just fine on my main domain (http://fablelane.com). It contains the exact same codes.

It's a Facebook application that uses the C# Facebook SDK to authenticate a user. When I sign in through my staging domain, I receive the following exception:

```
'Facebook.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'id'
```

In my Facebook settings, I have the following specified.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your error is the same you find in [Here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/270945)

The workaround is to download the latest version of the framework..